Object reference not set to an instance of an object: on Publish
When I click a publish button:

on the Database project in Visual Studio I cannot access the publish window and I just get a popup that says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Therefore any changes to the database are impossible.
my co-workers do not have this problem at all and if they had the issue dissapeared after updating Visual Studio
What I tried

Deleting all bin, obj & .vs folders Running .\devenv.exe
/ResetUserData Running .\devenv.exe /UpdateConfiguration &
.\devenv.exe /ClearCache
Update and re-install Visual    Studio
turn off all extensions I have tried to clean    and rebuild the
project
Delete folder ComponentModelCache on path C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version}
Reset Visual Studio to system Default
Sign in to the Visual Studio via different account

I suspect the issue is somewhere in the project and my machine since other projects works fine in this scenario.
Still other coleagues can change whatever they want and publish without any issues. On my coworker laptop the issue is gone even if I sign in with my own Profile and pull the branch where I have made changes.
Worth noting that other projects in the company does not run on the same framework. No project that runs on the same framework as the one that I am facing the issue can be tested, except a dummy project that I have created and there the issue is gone.
I am hopeless and it is frustrating to ask my coworkers to publish the changes for me every time a new field or table is required

Target platform of the Database Project - SQL Server 2012
Visual Studio version - Version 17.8.7
.NET framework version - Version 4.8.09037


Have you tried the answers here? visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object...

@TimSchmelter Ill try that and Ill close the question if it does end up working Thank you

@jakup: no need to close it yourself, just let me know, then i can close it as a duplicate of the other.

@TimSchmelter unfortunately it does not help...
I think there might be some issue on the project itself since on other projects this does not occur

Workaround:
Select properties of an entire solution:

Than change the configuration of Database project to any configuration and than back to the configuration you are using:

NOTE:
Do not commit the solution changes otherwise the problem occurs again...
Discard the changes and once you need to publish again repeat the process...

I came across this issue myself while getting the same error message and thought something in my install was jacked up.
I had created an x64 debug profile for projects in my solution and this seems to have been the cause of the issue for me.  As long as I was using this profile I was unable to publish the database project.
When selecting  "Any CPU" setting I was actually able to get it publish and show me the Publish database screen.


If you are still experiencing this, I wonder if this could be the same issue for you?
